# I'm an American, marrying a Brit in the Canary Islands

Tags: usa, marriage

Marrying in the Canary Islands and returning to US. What would be next step?

Comment: Next step for what?

Comment: The next step is a long honeymoon.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to follow the procedure for obtaining a [CR-1 visa (Immigrant Visa for a Spouse of a U.S. Citizen)](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/immigrate/family/immediate-relative.html) for your spouse. The CR-1 would apply (instead of the IR-1) because you will probably have been married for less than two years at the time you make the application (see the section on "Conditional Residence").

Comment: I somehow suspect that if the plan is to travel to the Canary Islands for a short visit, and get married there, and then move directly to the US, that the CR-1 application might run into problems.  In particular, do you know whether it's possible to begin the application before getting married, based on a plan to marry before the proposed date of arrival?

Comment: @phoog: I'm not sure about that. On further searching I found http://www.alllaw.com/articles/nolo/us-immigration/get-married-abroad-bring-your-foreign-fiance-to-u.s.html which explains the process in much more detail and also mentions the K-3 visa process.